# jQuery Mask não funciona em elementos criados de forma dinâmica

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando o [jQuery Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) para formatar moeda num formulário, e nesse formulário é possível adicionar vários valores de forma dinâmica e pra isso eu duplico a div que contém o input, só que ao duplicar essa div o jQuery mask para de funcionar neste novo input criado, como posso resolver isso?

Estrutura:

```
<div id="payment_draft">
    <div class="form-group col-xl-6">
        <label for="paid_value">Valor Pago</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control money_format" name="paid_value">
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn_add_payment">Duplicar</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.money_format').mask('#.##0,00', {reverse: true});

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_add_payment', function(){

        var payment = $('#payment_draft');
        var container = $('.payments_container'); //adiciona em outra div

        var copy = payment.clone();

        container.append(copy)
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a forma abaixo para aplicar o plugin automaticamente quando o campo ganhar o foco, inclusive campos clonados ou adicionados de forma dinâmica:

```
$(document).on("focus", ".money_format", function() { 
   $(this).mask('#.##0,00', {reverse: true});
});
```

Veja funcionado:

```js
$(document).on("focus", ".money_format", function() { 
   $(this).mask('#.##0,00', {reverse: true});
});


$(document).on('click', '.btn_add_payment', function(){

   var payment = $('#payment_draft');
   var container = $('.payments_container'); //adiciona em outra div
   
   var copy = payment.clone();
   
   container.append(copy)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.12/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<div class="payments_container">
   <div id="payment_draft">
       <div class="form-group col-xl-6">
           <label for="paid_value">Valor Pago</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control money_format" name="paid_value">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<button class="btn_add_payment">Duplicar</button>
```

> **Nota:** ao clonar a div, você está duplicando o `id="payment_draft"`. Um id deve ser único na página. Sugiro trocar
>   por `class="payment_draft"`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! O "payment_draft" eu coloquei só aqui de exemplo mesmo, mas não está assim lá não, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Clonar um HTML não irá clonar os `eventListener` apontando para os elementos desse HTML.

Como a mascara do jQuery é um `eventListener`, você precisa atribui-la para os elementos clonados também:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_add_payment', function(){

    var payment = $('#payment_draft');
    var container = $('.payments_container'); //adiciona em outra div

    var copy = payment.clone();
    copy.find('.money_format').mask('#.##0,00', {reverse: true});

    container.append(copy)
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, Funcionou, mas existe alguma forma de atribuir de forma automática?

Comment: Clonar com `payment.clone(true)` deveria clonar os listeners, mas não sei como é a implementação da mascara que você está utilizando. Não garanto que irá funcionar.

Comment: Automático de qual forma?

Comment: Usei clone(true) e clone(true, true) que vi que seria o "deep" e também não funcionou

Comment: @MauryDeveloper, automático no sentido de o event listener do mask ser "dinâmico", qualquer novo elemento criado com a classe "money_format" já funcionaria, é possivel?

Comment: Sim. Mas onde quer criar no html?

Comment: @MauryDeveloper, tem que funcionar em qualquer lugar, a resposta do Sam já soluciona isso

Comment: Eu iria adicionar evento `on` em lugar de `focus`.